# g.Raphael Hide y-axis label in

Tags: raphael, linechart, graphael

I add a line chart with g.Raphael.js like so:

```
var tl = paper.linechart(x, y, w, h, [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]], [trendline], { axis: "0 0 0 1", colors:['#fff'] });
```

Sometimes, "trendline" will be an empty array, which results in Y-axis labels of "NaN" and "Infinity". How can I hide those labels in those cases? 
I've tried playing with axisystep but that didn't make a difference. 
Perhaps line chart could use a "axisylabels" setting like the dots chart has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do the following to hide the labels in such cases:

```
var chart = paper.linechart(x, y, w, h,
    [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]], [trendline],
    { axis: "0 0 0 1", colors:['#fff'] });

// hide labels if there is no data
if (trendline.length == 0) {
    var y_labels = chart.axis[0].text.items;
    for (var i in y_labels) {
        y_labels[i].attr({'text': ""});
    };
}
```